# Kendo UI Column Chart data binding not working

Tags: kendo-ui, column-chart

In MVC application I am using Kendo column charts and I have the data as below.

| Type | Percentage | Date | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25.5 | 2/12 | #2456C7 |
| B | 70 | 2/13 | #2456C8 |
| B | 50 | 2/14 | #2456C8 |
| B | 55.5 | 2/15 | #2456C8 |
| A | 60.3 | 2/13 | #2456C8 |

I want to create a column chart with this data, chart should be categorized by Date and there should be multiple columns depending on the type.

I wrote the below code snippet but it isn't working, cannot see the data on UI.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<EntitiesA.Report>
                ()
                .Name("Report")
                .Title("ReportA")
                .Legend(legend => legend
                .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
                )
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Read(read => read.Action("MethodReport", "ReportController"))
                    .Group(group => group.Add(model => model.Type))
                    .Sort(sort => sort.Add(model => model.Date).Ascending())
                )
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Column(model => model.Percentage)
                        .Name("#= group.value # (Percentage)").CategoryField("Date").ColorField("Color");
                })
                .Legend(legend => legend
                    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
                )
                .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                    .Labels(labels => labels.Format("MM/DD"))
                )
                .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                                .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
                                .MajorUnit(20)
                                .Max(100)
                                .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
                )
                .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Format("{0:N0}")
                )
                )
```

I don't see any data in the graph it is blank how to fix it, am I missing any logic or piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you want a Date axis, right? If so you can also specify that via the CategoryAxis configuration:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Report>()
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Date()
                .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days)
                .Labels(labels => labels.Format("MM/dd"))
            )
           ...
  )
```

Passing some sample data renders the Chart - [example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/wHOcwOlS38e9tgdz19)